# Help me with adding render and rerender functionalities on page

Tags: visualforce, rerender, rendered

My requirement is whenever the checkbox **Did you confirm by DOB** is true. The required field DOB will display and when checkbox is false it will not.
[image]

Now the issue is when i am making the check box true field display but when i make it false it shows the following messsage and does not disappear from page

[image]

Please verify my code and tell me where is the problem. **Also please verify that i am following the right way to make the field required. As i want this field only when the checkbox is true.** 
**This is the code**

```
          <apex:inputcheckbox value="{!chkBx2}" label="Did you confirm by DOB" >    
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="thePanel" action="{!click2}"/>    
          </apex:inputcheckbox>
            <apex:outputPanel id="thePanel" >                 
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!displayInputputText}">
              <apex:outputLabel escape="true" id="Component49" style="width:228px;" value="{!$ObjectType.BGC_Criminal_Search_Record__c.fields.DOB__c.label} "/>
              <apex:inputField id="Component43" value="{!record.DOB__c}"  required="{!IF(chkBx2,true,false)}" />             
              </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:outputPanel>
```

---

```
  public Boolean displayInputputText{get;set;}
  public Boolean chkBx2{get;set;}
      public PageReference click2(){    
    if(chkBx2){
      displayInputputText = true;
    }
    else{
      displayInputputText = false;
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get this working by adding the `immediate="true"` attribute to your [`<apex:actionSupport>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionSupport.htm) component. With that flag set, the Visualforce runtime won't validate other components prior to doing the form submission and allowing you to rerender the the page elements you need:

> A Boolean value that specifies whether the action associated with this component should happen immediately, without processing any validation rules associated with the fields on the page. If set to true, the action happens immediately and validation rules are skipped. If not specified, this value defaults to false.